# System backup and restore with help of Google's system backup feature doesn't seem to work

Tags: restore, google-backup

I have had my phone set up from the start to backup to Google. I have done 3 resets now and none of my settings and apps or anything seem to come back. Is there a way to force this to happen? Perhaps, I'm mistaken thinking that this even happens?

Phone is a Samsung S2 GT-I9100 running Android 4.0.4.

Comment: Could you provide the make/model and Android version of the phone?

Comment: Doesn't exactly answer your question -- but that's nothing "unusual". This normally works only to 50%. To be more precise: Backup works... There are plenty reports about restore never working, though I heard rumors that some succeeded with it...

Comment: @onik I have added the phone ver to the question. I have a friend who has a S3 and seems to work perfectly for him. Nothing came back to my phone at all only the contact from sync with gmail. The texts, settings, apps etc etc none came back :(

Comment: My apps came back after a reset, but my internet went down and only half got restored. I would like to automatically download the other half.

Comment: @Izzy those are not rumors I'm one of them who had got the backup from Google. But you have to be sure that your data is backed up while you are using syncing option. I often check it under play store apps where they report about which apps are synced to Google server. Also I got back my contacts from there too.

Comment: @avirk Never had trouble with contacts or calendar -- that's something completely different. It's just the "restore" part of apps/data having trouble: sometimes not starting at all, other times aborting before being finished (with the user being unable to resume). From the reports I've read, it seems pretty unreliable. If you know a way to make sure it works, please provide an answer -- you would make more than the OP happy with that :)

Comment: I just found something that *might* be helpful. Not using Google's Cloud Backup, I cannot test -- but you might want to take a look at my [answer here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/42629/16575) explaining some details of the mechanism, extracted from the developer's documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is very temperamental and depends on the device using the Google setup wizard.

It works a bit too well on my s2 with Cyanogen 10 - Cyanogen uses the default Google setup wizard.

When you reset, ensure you follow the setup wizard, and especially notice the part about restore - it should be checked by default, but may not be.

Comment: It is checked by default. It failed downloading half of the apps on my Nexus 7 due to the internet going out. So I tried to reset it again...but this time it only tried to download the half that completed the last time. Good bye Broken Sword saves :'(

Comment: @row1 It is *very* temperamental - like I said. It never worked on my old phone, but it does on my S2. It is also dependant on the ROM in question :( You should use a dedicated backup app if you *really* want to keep your data.

Comment: @row1 If you hadn't reset it again, it would have downloaded the rest eventually.