# "App Data" Sync & "App Data" Backup both are same?

Tags: sync, app-data

May be its silly but I'm curious to know the actual fact. I searched google and this site a lot but didn't got satisfiable result. So asking.

There is "App Data" sync in Settings->Accounts->Google
There is also Backup My Data in Settings->Backup & Reset

1. Are they same??

I know that if I flash my device then all apps I get by restore. how its being done??

1. one of my app after restoration asked me to update. "SMS Backup & Restore" if Google restores by installing from Google play why after restoring it wants to update?? last update date of that app in Google play was older than today's date. So it seems that Google installed an older version of the app though there is a new version
2. So do Android uploads whole binaries and app local data to the Google server from the device?? or Google tracks which apps were last installed in the device & just re installs those last installed apps according to version from Google play??

Comment: Related: [What info does Google backup?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/15434/16575) / [What exactly is this App Data that is being backed up to Google?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/47586/16575) / [What exactly is synced with Google?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/30346/16575) / [Google Backup: Multiple devices using the same account - what happens on Restore?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42245/16575)

Comment: @Izzy I read all these before. But my question is little different I think. cause I'm getting restore of an old version of app whereas there exists a new in google play. So I want to know if google backup the apk files which are in my device direct from my device?? or just installs apps from google play and restores the app datas.

Comment: I couldn't know you've read that already (as you didn't mention it – which would have been a good idea :) Up to my knowledge, only references to the apps are backed-up (not the `.apk` files themselves, which *Google* already has – you've installed them from there, remember?). I'm not sure about side-loaded apps and whether those are backed-up at all (if they aren't available at *Google Play*).