# Wifi passwords were not restored on a new device

Tags: wi-fi, backup, restore, password

I got a new galaxy nexus phone running 4.2.2 and I noticed my WiFi passwords were not restored to this device.

I skipped the account login upon first start, but added it later on. Am I missing something? I'm pretty sure my passwords were automatically synced when I got a nexus 7 tablet last year.

Many thanks for helping with this.

Comment: Sorry to say so, but yes: You missed to backup them separately. While Google Cloud backup seems to work fine for some, it's reportedly flaky. You cannot tell it when or what to restore, and sometimes it restores all, while at other times parts or even nothing at all. Should be better with "newer" Android versions, but there are no guarantees.

Comment: Does that mean I can still back up passwords on my tablet and then run restore them on my new phone?

Comment: If you still have the first device, you could even try to factory-reset the second and accept the Google account straight away (not sure if that helps, though). Apart from that, there are a few apps for root users offering to backup/restore them. And if both devices are running Android 4.x, without root you might want to give *Helium Backup* a try. Koush might have implemented that part as well meanwhile.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try, although I'm pretty disappointed with the flakiness of the restore feature

Comment: Agreed, and that's not something Google "proudly announces" (as with the new DeviceManager, which cannot locate any of my 4 Google-connected devices; many others having similar issues, but still it is announced as the killer-feature). Using e.g. *Helium* in parallel, you can even backup before you reset and selectively restore things after, so the factory reset won't cause too much harm. Thing is, I doubt it will work, see Dan's answer to [Google Backup: Multiple devices using the same account - what happens on Restore?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42245/16575)

Comment: Helium is just a wrapper around `bmgr`, with overburdened and confusing UI. Sometimes running `adb shell bmgr restore _id_of_set_ com.android.providers.settings` works for me, but it is unreliable.