# How do I restore my Android tablet from Google servers?

Tags: restore, google-backup

I sent my Android tablet for repair and it came back from the manufacturer with the data and applications missing.  How do I restore the tablet from the `Settings -> Backup` Google servers?

Answer (score 1):

It's either restored when you first configure your Android account on the device and accept the Cloud Backup, or not at all. There's no way to trigger it manually except for factory-resetting and re-configuring the account (sometimes it even requires to use a different SIM to trigger a complete restore, as one user reported; I just cannot find the reference at the moment).

You'll find a lot of details in the answers to [Google Backup: Multiple devices using the same account - what happens on Restore?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/42245/16575).