# Restore settings from Google account

Tags: restore, google, 5.1-lollipop

I updated Android manually but all my settings are now lost.

I remember that in the previous updates it would download all the apps again and restore settings from my Google Account.

But this time I skipped the Google Account setup after booting. I thought I can do it later. Now I added the account, but nothing gets restored :(

Comment: You only said, you did _manually_. No, chance until and unless it is synced on google servers. If synced, I suggest remove your account and then again add it back. But, this time don't skip _"Back up and restore date from google servers."_

Comment: The answers on [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42245/google-backup-multiple-devices-using-the-same-account-what-happens-on-restore?rq=1) question might be useful.