# How can I restore remembered wifi networks and saved wifi passwords?

Tags: wi-fi, google-account

I know this question has been asked before and I have searched google for far too long to not have an answer.

So the situation is

- I have done a data wipe and a clean install.
- During the setup process I did not choose to restore anything.
- After the installation I went to Settings > Backup & reset and enabled Automatic restore.
- Yet no saved wifi networks or passwords were restored.

I cannot find anything related to Network restore under Settings > Google

- Android 6.0.1
- Gapps 6.0
- Nexus 5

Comment: You need to backup your WiFi password __before__ the data wipe.

Answer (score 2):

When you set up a phone and choose not to restore its previous backups, it creates a new "set" of backup data, independent of your old backups. From now on, your phone will only backup to and restore from this new set.

There's no simple way to make it switch back to the old set, to restore your old Wi-Fi settings, but [my answer on a question about backing up multiple devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/49425/12442) explains how a power user can use the `bmgr` tool to find old sets of backup data and switch to (i.e. restore from) a different set. I'm afraid you'll have to look at the data and use your judgement: there's no one step-by-step solution that will work for every case.

Comment: One could also manually backup the **wpa_supplicant.conf**.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Not when you've already wiped the phone, you can't.

Comment: Well, of course one backups first, and wipes second.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman That's not what this question is about. OP has already wiped the phone and wants to retrieve the settings from Google Backup.